# Is the kernel of the coderivative infinite-dimensional?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, differential-operators

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}$
$\newcommand{\euc}{\mathcal{e}}$
$\newcommand{\Cof}{\operatorname{Cof}}$
$\newcommand{\Det}{\operatorname{Det}}$

Let $M,N$ be smooth $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds (perhaps with smooth boundary),  and let $\, f:M \to N$ be a smooth **immersion**. Let $\Omega^k(M,f^*TN)$ be the space of $f^*TN$-valued $k$-forms.

Let $d:\Omega^k(M,f^*TN) \to \Omega^{k+1}(M,f^*TN)$ be the covariant exterior derivative associated with the pullback connection of the Levi-Civita connection on $N$ (via $f$), and let $\delta$ be its adjoint.

Denote $\delta_{k}:\Omega^k(M,f^*TN) \to \Omega^{k-1}(M,f^*TN)$.

**Question:** Is $\ker \delta_1$ is infinite dimensional?

Since $\delta=\star d \star$ (up to sign), $\dim(\ker \delta_1)=\dim(\ker d_{n-1})$. So, this is a question about $d$.

---

**Edit:**

In the special case where $N$ is flat, $\delta_{k} \circ \delta_{k+1}=0$, so $\operatorname{Image}(\delta_{k+1}) \subseteq \ker(\delta_k)$.

In particulr, $\operatorname{Image}(\delta_{2}) \subseteq \ker(\delta_1)$.

Is $\operatorname{Image}(\delta_{2})$ is infinite-dimensional? Can we at least something when $N=\mathbb{R}^n$? or even when $M=N=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Let's see what happens when $M=N=\mathbb{R}^n,f=\operatorname{Id}$:

$$ d_{n-1}(\sigma)(e_1,...,e_n)=\sum_{j=1}^{d} (-1)^{j+1} \nabla^{T\mathbb{R}^n}_{e_j} \big( \sigma(e_1,...,\hat{e_j},...,e_d) \big)$$

Write $\sigma=(-1)^{j+1}a_j^idx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \hat{dx^j} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^d \otimes e_i, a_j^i \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Then $ \sigma(e_1,...,\hat{e_j},...,e_d)=(-1)^{j+1}a_j^i e_i $, so

$$ \nabla^{T\mathbb{R}^n}_{e_j} \big( \sigma(e_1,...,\hat{e_j},...,e_d) \big)= \nabla^{T\mathbb{R}^n}_{e_j}((-1)^{j+1}a_j^i e_i)=(-1)^{j+1}\frac{\partial a_j^i}{\partial x_j}e_i.$$

Thus, $$\sigma \in \ker d_{n-1} \iff  \frac{\partial a_j^i}{\partial x_j}e_i=0 $$ (in the last term there is a double summation, on $i,j$).

Since $e_i$ are independent, this is equivalent to
$$\sum_{j=1}^d \frac{\partial a_j^i}{\partial x_j}=0 \, \text{ for all } \, i=1,...,d $$

Denoting $\bar a^i=(a_1^i,...,a_d^i)$, we get that $\operatorname{div} (\bar a^i)=0$.

I guess it shouldn't be too hard to see now that $\dim(\ker d_{n-1}) = \infty$. (By taking the $a_j^i$ to be constants, one immediately gets $\dim(\ker d_{n-1}) \ge n^2$. Since the condition on the divergence do not touch $\frac{\partial a_j^i}{\partial x_k}$ for $k \neq j$, it seems plausible that the dimension is indeed infinite. Perhaps someone can come with a slick argument to show this.)

The next case we should try is $M=N=\mathbb{R}^d$, and $f$ an arbitrary mapping....

---

**Comment:**

I know that  $\operatorname{Cof}(df) \in \ker \delta_1$, where $\operatorname{Cof}(df)$ is the corresponding *cofactor map* of $df$:
  $$ \Cof df= (-1)^{d-1} \star_{f^*TN}^{n-1} (\wedge^{n-1} df) \star_{TM}^1. $$

Since $f$ is an immersion, $\operatorname{Cof}(df) \neq 0$, so $\dim (\ker \delta_1 ) \ge 1$.

For my purposes, It would suffice to know that $\ker \delta_1$ always contains elements which are linearly independent of $\Cof df$.

Comment: Myself I suspect that $\dim\ker(\delta)=\infty$ since $\dim \ker(d)\cap\ker(\delta)<\infty$ and $\dim\ker(d)$ tends to be infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the vector field $v$ is a non-vanishing covariantly constant on $N$, then its pullback $f^*v$ is a constant section of $f^*TN \to M$ with respect to the pulled back connection. Then, for any $(n-1)$-form $\alpha$ and $(n-2)$-form $\beta$ on $M$, we have $d_{n-2} (\beta \otimes f^*v) = (d\beta) \otimes f^*v$ and $d_{n-1} (\alpha \otimes f^*v) = (d\alpha) \otimes f^*v$, where I used $d$ to denote the usual de Rham exterior derivative. Then clearly, $\mathrm{im}(d) \otimes f^*v \subseteq \ker d_{n-1}$ is an infinite dimensional subspace.

On the other hand, suppose that there are no non-vanishing constant sections of $f^*TN \to M$. We might still be able to find some differential operator $q \colon \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(\Lambda^{n-1}T^*M \otimes_M f^*TN)$ whose image lands inside $\ker d_{n-1}$, that is $d_{n-1} \circ q = 0$. The trick is to first dualize. As you noted, $d_{n-1}^* = d_0$, up to conjugation by invertible operators. Then any "compatibility operator" $q^*$, such that $q^* \circ d_0 = 0$, gives us a candidate $q = (q^*)^*$, because $d_{n-1} \circ q = d_0^* \circ (q^*)^* = (q^* \circ d_0)^*$.

The non-existence of non-trivial constant sections of $f^*TN \to M$ means that there exist integrability conditions for the equation $d_0 v = 0$. In particular, after some massaging, we can come up with an operator $C\colon \Gamma(T^*M \otimes_M f^*TN) \to \Gamma(f^*TN)$ such that $C\circ d_0 = \mathrm{id}$. As a consequence, we have the identity $(\mathrm{id} - d_0 \circ C) \circ d_0 = d_0 - d_0 \circ (C\circ d_0) = 0$. Hence we have found a compatibility operator $q^* = \mathrm{id} - d_0 \circ C$, from which $q = \mathrm{id} - C^* \circ d_{n-1}$. In conclusion, we have $\mathrm{im}(q) \subseteq \ker d_{n-1}$.

It remains to check that $\mathrm{im}(q)$ is indeed infinite dimensional. I don't have a slick argument for that, at the moment. But I'm sure that in individual cases it should not be hard to establish, at the very least by looking at the effect of $q$ on jets of higher and higher order at some fixed point $x\in M$.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is very interesting. I have some questions: (1) Is it known that $\operatorname{image}(d_{n-2})$ is infinite-dimensional? (I only know that  $\operatorname{image}(d_{n-2})+\operatorname{image}(\delta_{n}) $ is infinite-dim: This follows from the Hodge decomposition theorem together with the facts that the space of harmonic forms is finite-dim and the space of all forms of a certain degree is infinite-dim ). (2) I would really like to know more about what exactly do you mean by "integrability conditions", and how you lift them to build an operator $C$.

Comment: (Finally, I think there is a typo: you meant to write $d_1$ instead of $d_0$...)

Comment: I meant the operator $d_0\colon \Gamma(f^*TN) \to \Gamma(T^*M\otimes_M f^*TN)$. The identity $\beta \wedge (d_{n-1} \alpha) + (d_0\beta) \wedge \alpha = d_{n-1} (\beta \wedge \alpha)$ shows that, up to signs, $d_{n-1}^* = d_0$ (integrate both sides with compactly supported arguments to check). These formulas are for usual forms, but using appropriate covariant derivatives they work also for vector valued forms.

Comment: Look again at the answer by Craig. We have $d_{n-2} (f(x_{n-1}) dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{n-2}) = f' (x_{n-1}) dx_{n-1} \wedge dx_1 \cdots \wedge dx_{n-2}$. Unless $f(x_{n-1})$ is constant, you get a non-zero image in $\mathrm{im}(d_{n-2})$, which hence contains at least this infinite dimensional subspace. If you have an explicit form of the $q$ operator, you could probably use the same trick, by looking carefully at its components.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Roughly speaking, given a differential equation $Dv = 0$, an integrability condition is any differential consequence $Iv := (C\circ D) v=0$, where the operator $I$ is of the same or lower order than $D$ itself. Example: in your case, let $D=d_0$ and $C=d_1$, note that $(d_1)_j (d_0)_k (f^* v^i) = -f^*(R_{jkl}{}^i v^l)$, where $R_{jkl}{}^i$ is the Riemann tensor on $N$. This integrability condition is of order zero, while $d_0$ was of order $1$. As an exercise, find more integrability conditions, which will involve derivatives of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: Thanks. I will think more about what you are saying. I agree now with $d_{n-1}^*=d_0$ (so I guess the $d_1$ in your answer are supposed to be replaced by $d_0$?). Also, just to make sure I didn't miss anything: Does your argument hold for a general vector bundle $E$ over $M$? (not of the specific form $f^*TN$)?

Comment: @AsafShachar, ah yes, those $d_1$'s were the typos. Sorry for the confusion! And yes, the argument applies equally well to any vector bundle with a connection.

Comment: Thanks. I admit I still  don't think it's trivial that injectivity of $d_0$ implies existence of an operator $C$ s.t $C \circ d_0=Id_{f^*TN}$. (Of course, it is a necessary condition, but why is it sufficient? Is there a general theory of invertibility of *injective* differential operators between vector bundles or is it something which depends on the special features of this specific problem/operator $d_0$?). Also, I am not sure what you mean by looking at "fixed points" of $M$:...

Comment: Fixed points of which map? I apologize for the further disturbance, but I feel your solution lies a too far from my comfort zone and I would like to "fill in the gap":)

Comment: @AsafShachar, you are overthinking the situation. First, read "fixed point ..." as "some given point...". More importantly, if you don't under stand what that paragraph of the answer says, just ignore it and instead replace it by [this comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255164/is-the-kernel-of-the-coderivative-infinite-dimensional/266054?noredirect=1#comment656707_266054). For the rest, it would really help for you to have a "hands on" example where you can check everything by direct calculations instead of relying on a general theory.

Comment: Here are some concrete exercises to fill in the gaps. Just think of a general vector bundle $E$ with connection $\nabla$ and curvature $[\nabla_i,\nabla_j] v^a \sim R_{ijb}{}^a v^b$.
(1) Find an operator $C$ such that $C\circ \nabla v^a = (R_{ijb}{}^a v^b, (\nabla_i R_{jkb}{}^a) v^b, (\nabla_i\nabla_j R_{klb}{}^a v^b, \ldots)$. Terminate at whichever order you like.
(2) Given a fiber-wise injective map of vector bundles $v^a \mapsto Q_A^b v^b$ (a 0-th order operator), find a left inverse $P\circ Q = \mathrm{id}_E$.
(3) Prove local existence for $\nabla v = 0$ if (1) is never injective.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly infinite dimensional in the flat case.

$\ker\delta_1 =\ker d_{n-1}$

And in a coordinate chart with coordinates $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ take various $f\in C^\infty(M)$ with support in the chart, so

$df\wedge dx_1 \wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{n-2} \in \ker d_{n-1}$